# SSR: Deferring certain components for loading on the client (especially those with window in them)

Tags: react-loadable

So, I'm moving from `react-async-component` to `react-loadable` bc of a bug that isn't being fixed. `react-async-component` has this nifty `serverMode` that allows you to tell it to never load a component on the server.

This can be useful for admin screens and especially for certain 3rd party components that reference the `window` object on the server, without checking for its existence.

WhenI used `preloadAll`, it literally gets everything because there doesn't seem to be a way to exclude items from the selection. Or is there?

It would be nice to see a `serverMode` option on the `Loadable` call. But in the meantime, is there a way to exclude certain patterns from being included in `preloadAll` on the server?